# xamarin.forms camera with custom controls

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin and I am looking for Camera in Xamarin.Form Prortable Class Library with custom controls on camera like Delete last photo, Delete All, Save.

I need all there controls over the camera. I am attaching an Image for clear picture. **I need this in Xamarin.Forms PCL**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this myself  by using Moment code, I have customized the code for Video.

1. Click on Capture Icon, it will not show the timer but it will still record
2. Click on left top corner of Flash icon, video will  stop and recorded
3. It will save with name test.mp4

here is the code for you can clone

https://github.com/yadavparveen/Xamarin-Video